# Any reason not to import tag information from the main Stack Exchange meta site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, tags, tag-excerpt

I noticed that the [review](/questions/tagged/review) tag doesn't have any information attached to it. While I could spend time writing a description for it, I thought I might reuse the same text that the review tag has on the main Stack Exchange meta site. In fact, I could do this for all  generic tags such as:

- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions)
- [design](/questions/tagged/design)
- [election](/questions/tagged/election)
- [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators)
- [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation)
- [review](/questions/tagged/review)
- [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions)

Assume that I'll read the descriptions first and remove any site-specific information. Is there any reason not to do this? Is there any automated way to do it?

On further thought, and this is likely a main site meta question, why aren't these general tags maintained centrally so that they have the same definitions across all sites?

EDIT: I've done some more searching and turned up related questions on meta.SO. One mentions that [some mandatory and moderator-only tags and wiki info are pushed out to all meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66425/can-the-tag-wikis-for-the-mandatory-tags-and-moderator-only-tags-be-propagated-t). The information can then be overwritten on the 'child' meta sites. There's also a current question about [finding plagiarized text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173807/how-can-tag-wiki-plagiarism-be-found-effectively) in the tag-wiki information. Technically, I'm advocating plagiarism, although in my first attempt with [election](/questions/tagged/election) I did include a statement and reference to the source.

Answer (score 3):

[PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/any-reason-not-to-import-tag-information-from-the-main-stackexchange-meta-site/4851#4851) contain links which explain why not doing this in an automatic fashion.

However, I second your effort on manually filling excerpts and wikis for tags in GIS Meta. I also do that sporadically when I ask or answer a question which have a tag at least with no excerpt.

Usually I will look at the main [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site and see if there is a corresponding tag there. If there is, I will evaluate if I only need to copy-paste the text and give proper attribution or if I can modify/improve it somehow.

I also will usually add/edit the most relevant tags I can to a meta post, among other edits (title, body, etc.). It is useful for finding content, duplicates, etc. (like the in main site).

Answer (score 2):

A feature request like this would need to be implemented at the Meta Stack Exchange level rather than here at Meta GIS SE but it has already been discussed there as:

[Unifying descriptions for all tags across SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300923/call-to-unify-descriptions-for-all-tags-accros-se-sites)

which was made a duplicate of [Why don't we add a question with the same tag on multiple Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268885/why-dont-we-add-a-question-with-the-same-tag-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites) and set to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

I think the two are somewhat oblique duplicates and focus more on Main rather than Meta sites but in any event this is not something we have control over here at GIS SE so I am deferring it to SE.